# Unique solution to $x^4 + 7x -1 = 0$ on $[0,1]$ (Banach's fixed point theorem)

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, fixed-point-theorems

I want to show that $x^4 + 7x -1 = 0$ has a unique solution on $[0,1]$.

The idea is to use Banach's fixed point theorem. However, I see a problem with this as the statement of the theorem says that the function $f$ has to be defined from a complete metric space to itself. While $[0,1]$ is complete (as a closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ which is complete) the function $f(x) = x ^ 4 + 8x - 1 $ does not have an image only in $[0,1]$.

What am I missing/not understanding here?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Absolutely sure that "the idea is to use Banach fixed point theorem"?

Comment: The chapter is 'Complete metric spaces' and it says use theorem X, which states Banach fixed point theorem but for intervals in $R$.

Comment: I am asking this because, by the IVT, the result is a direct consequence of the fact that $f$ is increasing on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)\lt0\lt f(1)$.

Comment: Could you state that the Banach's fixed point theorem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to apply [Banach fixed-point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem) to the function
$$f(x)=\frac{1-x^4}7$$
on the interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Is $f(x)$ a self map on $[0,1]$?

Comment: @stephan If $x\in[0,1]$, then $x^4\in[0,1]$ and $1-x^4\in[0,1]$. Consequently, $f(x)\in[0,\frac17]\subseteq[0,1]$.

Comment: I am  confused about self-map definition. Don't we  say $T:[0,1]\longrightarrow [0,1]$ is a self map if Domain=Codomain?

Comment: Well, writing $f(x)=\frac{1-x^4}7$ defines a function from $[0,1]$ to $[0,1]$. As I suspect that this might result in a longer exchange, maybe we could [continue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2022/11/10) (if you know how to use chat)? So that we do not leave too many comments here.

Comment: @stephan In case it helps, you can have a look at answers to this question: [How to choose interval for Banach's fixed point theorem?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2351629)